# AMQP gem specifying a dead letter exchange

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

I've specified a queue on the RabbitMQ server called `MyQueue`. It is durable and has `x-dead-letter-exchange` set to `MyQueue.DLX`.

(I also have an exchange called `MyExchange` bound to that queue, and another exchange called `MyQueue.DLX`, but I don't believe this is important to the question)

If I use ruby's `amqp` gem to subscribe to those messages I would do it like this:

```
# Doing this before and in a new thread has to do with how my code is structured
# shown here in case it has a bearing on the question
Thread.new do
  AMQP.start('amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672')
end

EventMachine.next_tick do
  channel = AMQP::Channel.new(AMQP.connection)

  queue = channel.queue("MyQueue", :durable => true, :'x-dead-letter-exchange' => "MyQueue.DLX")

  queue.subscribe(:ack => true) do |metadata, payload|
    p metadata
    p payload
  end
end
```

If I execute this code with the queues and exchanges already created and bound (as they need to be in my set up) then RabbitMQ throws the following error in its logs:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 19-Aug-2013::14:25:53 ===
connection <0.19654.2>, channel 2 - soft error:
{amqp_error,precondition_failed,
        "inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange'for queue 'MyQueue' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'MyQueue.DLX' of type 'longstr'",
        'queue.declare'}
```

Which seems to be saying that I *haven't* specified the same Dead Letter Exchange as the pre-existing queue - but I believe I have with the `queue = ...` line.

Any ideas?

Comment: So does your code work successfully if you don't have any of your queues or exchanges declared?

Comment: If I declare my queues without the dead letter exchange set then yes, it does work - I think it's just that I don't know how to specify the DLX with the ruby gem.

Answer (score 3):

The DLX info is passed in the `arguments` option:

```
queue = channel.queue("MyQueue", {durable: true, arguments: {"x-dead-letter-exchange" => "MyQueue.DLX"}})
```

Comment: Here's documentation for the `bunny` gem from the same author. IIRC, it has been deprecated in favor of the `amqp` gem, but they are rather similar.

https://github.com/ruby-amqp/rubybunny.info/blob/master/articles/extensions.md#dead-letter-exchange-dlx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, even though using @Karl Wilbur s format for the options.

Looks like your "MyQueue" already exists on the RabbitMQ server (durable: true) and it exists without a dead letter exchange configuration.

```
queue = channel.queue("MyQueue", :durable => true, :'x-dead-letter-exchange' => "MyQueue.DLX")
```

this will not create a new queue if one already exists by the name "MyQueue". Instead it will try to connect to the existing one, but the options/arguments etc have to be the same or you get an error like the one you got.

All you have to do is delete the old one and run your code again (with Karl's suggestion).

I used the RabbitMQ management GUI to delete mine. see [here re deleting queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742938/deleting-queues-in-rabbitmq)