# How to delete a queue in rabbit mq

Tags: queue, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmctl using pika library.
I use the following code to create a Producer

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import time
import json
import datetime


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()



channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    #print " current time: %s "  % (str(int((time.time())*1000)))

    print body

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello',
                      no_ack=True)


channel.start_consuming()
```

Since I create an existing queue everytime (Over-write the creation of queue in case if queue is not created) The queue has been corrupted due to this.and now I want to delete the queue..how do i do that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since this seems to be a maintenance procedure, and not something you'll be doing routinely on your code, you should probably be using the [RabbitMQ management plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) and delete the queue from there.

Anyway, you can delete it from pika with:

```
channel.queue_delete(queue='hello')
```

https://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/channel.html#pika.channel.Channel.queue_delete

Answer (score 8):

The detailed answer is as follows  (with reference to above very helpful and useful answer)

```
import pika


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
               'localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()


channel.queue_delete(queue='hello')

connection.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

#### GUI rabbitMQ mgm't made that easy

```
$ sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

http://localhost:15672/#/queues

Username : guest

password : guest

---

inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742938/deleting-queues-in-rabbitmq)