# RabbitMQ - purge a queue from all of its unacked messages

Tags: rabbitmq

I have thousands of unacked messages in my dev environment which I can't restart.
Is there a way to remove (purge) all messages even if they are unacknowledged?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Close the channel that the unacked messages reside on, which will nack them back into the queue, then call purge.

Comment: How do you find the channel that the unacked message resides on?

Comment: @grayaii in you rabbitmq console..if you click on the queue with unacked meesages there will be a consumers section inside that you will find channels related to it.

Comment: Thanks! This has worked for me: I stopped the consumer for the queue, then the messages have moved into the bucket and then I was able to delete them with the Purge button.

Comment: How do you "Close the channel"?

Answer (score 24):

You have to make consumer `ack` them (or `nack`) and only after that they will be removed. Alternatively you can shutdown consumers and purge the queue completely.

If you are looking for some way to purge all unacked messages - there are no such feature nor in AMQP protocol neither in RabbitMQ.

It looks like your consumer is the cause of the problem, so you have to adjust it (rewrite) to release message immediately after it processed or failed.

Comment: There is queue purge in AMQP: http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.purge

Comment: It doesn't purge unacked messages. From the `queue.purge` method doc block: `This method removes all messages from a queue which are >>> not awaiting acknowledgment <<<`, which is strict AMQP protocol implementation.

Comment: @pinepain i spent a while writing code to find queues with messages. then call the `purge` command and then wait in a loop but the queues never emptied. thanks for the clarification. i'll have to rethink my approach.

Answer (score 4):

Once there are no "ready" messages in the queue, delete it and recreate.

Answer (score 2):

**YOU WILL LOSE THE QUEUE CONTENTS with this method.**

You need to put messages back into the queue before you can purge them:

- close the channel
- [close the connection](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2016-08-08-how-to-close-all-connections-rabbitmq.html) (the script doesn't work for me)

As an alternative, this doesn't require to wait:

- [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742938/deleting-queues-in-rabbitmq?rq=1) and recreate the queue
- restart the server

Comment: And then get fired.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `basic.recover` to force all unacked messages to be re-enqueued to a channel that failed. Be aware of the errata concerning this function specifying that only the requeue mode is supported by RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1):

One way this can happen is if the consumer is stuck recycling the same messages due to a processing error.  In this case, [the RabbitMQ queue management interface](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-05-27-part3-rabbitmq-for-beginners_the-management-interface.html#queues) may show the messages as *Unacked*, but really they are being read from the queue and processed (to the point of the failure) then requeued (to enable a retry) at a rapid pace -- *maybe thousands of times per second*.

During this loop, the messages exist briefly in the *Ready* state, but are immediately removed again by you application -- and the cycle begins again.  As an example, [this auto-requeue behavior is the default for Spring AMQP.](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-spring-amqp.html)

Since the messages are never left in the Ready state, the Management Interface's <kbd>Get Message(s)</kbd> button is unlikely work.  What can work, if you have queue access, is to **run a separate custom consumer instance**, perhaps locally, but with the specific intent of removing and not requeuing the messages in question.

By RabbitMQ's [*Fair Dispatch*](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) mechanism, your additional consumer will *likely* receive the messages in question and have the opportunity to perform your custom handling.

You might even write a custom utility to do this, with logic to filter, analyze, or deadletter the messages of interest.

Answer (score 0):

For software developer use below code.

**channel.purgeQueue(queue-name);**

if we use this code the Queue will be clear and same queue will exist.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to clear the contents of the queue, then you can use the AMQP method `queue.purge`: There is queue purge in AMQP: http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.purge

You could do similar using the management plugin.