# how to retrieve unack message from queue using rabbitmq java client

Tags: java, client, rabbitmq, recover

I am looking for a way to retrieve unack messages and put them back in ready state so that my consumer can again send back those messages.
[image]

I am using java client to get messages, these are my prog to send and retrieve messages. I read there is a methode basicRecover() which will put message back in queue.

```
SendMessage
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    String message = "message goes here";

    channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
    System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
}
channel.close();
connection.close();
```

}

```
Retrieve
try
    {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("10.4.4.19");
        factory.setUsername("test");
        factory.setPassword("test");
            //factory.setPort(5267);
        connection=factory.newConnection();
        channel=connection.createChannel();
        channel.basicQos(1);
        QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);

        for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
        {
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
            System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
           // Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);
            channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);

        }
        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error:"+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

can anyone plse provide me a code snippet so that the unack message can be put back in ready state and I can use my retrieve prog to read them.

Comment: This answer is somehow related to your question too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114230/rabbimq-purge-a-queue-from-all-of-its-unacked-mesasges/25116528#25116528

Answer (score 1):

If you don't execute `channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);` than the message will be (eventually) redelivered. You don't have to inform the service that the message was NOT delivered, it works on the principal that anything that was NOT acknowledged as delivered was NOT delivered.

http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric5/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.rabbitmq.2.4/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html

But as you will read in above link the only way to un-acknowledge the message is to kill/close the connection to service.