# Rabbitmq can not purge all messages in the queue

Tags: rabbitmq, mq

I am using rabbitmq, and I try to purge a queue by using commands like below:

```
[root@test xxx]# rabbitmqctl purge_queue metering.sample
Purging queue 'metering.sample' in vhost '/' ...

[root@test xxx]# rabbitmqadmin purge queue 
name=metering.sample
queue purged

[root@test xxx]# rabbitmqctl list_queues | grep sample
metering.sample 17172
```

Initially, the queue was filled with 296533 messages, after I ran both of the commands, the queue is still filled with 17172 messages. (I am sure there is no publisher running anymore)

why did it happen? is it a bug or I used it by wrong way?
need some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: May be those messages were quickly added to the queue after it has been purged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that the unacked messages are not purged by those commands.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25116528/2047138