# How to acknowledge all the unacked messages present in a RabbitMQ queue using REST API from Mule 3

Tags: rabbitmq, mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, rabbitmq-exchange

I have to acknowledge all the unacknowledged message and make the count zero. If the message is in ready so the using the purge requester (DELETE http://localhost:8767/api/queues/vhost/name/contents) I am able to purge and remove the messages but if it is in unacked then this purge is not working or count still showing in the unacked section.

Kindly suggest how to use the REST API of RabbitMQ to ACK all the messages in the queue and make the count as zero.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114230/rabbitmq-purge-a-queue-from-all-of-its-unacked-messages

Answer (score 0):

you can ack them or purge queue in rabbitmq management

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).