# spring boot rabbitmq dead letter queue config not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, dead-letter

I config spring boot rabbit' dead letter queue, but ErrorHandler never receive any message. I search all the questiones about dead letter queue, but could not figure out. Can anyone help me ?

RabbitConfig.java to config dead letter queue/exchange:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig {

public final static String MAIL_QUEUE = "mail_queue";

public final static String DEAD_LETTER_EXCHANGE = "dead_letter_exchange";

public final static String DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE = "dead_letter_queue";

public static Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();

static {
    args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", DEAD_LETTER_EXCHANGE);
    //args.put("x-dead-letter-routing-key", DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE);
    args.put("x-message-ttl", 5000);
}

@Bean
public Queue mailQueue() {
    return new Queue(MAIL_QUEUE, true, false, false, args);
}

@Bean
public Queue deadLetterQueue() {
    return new Queue(DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE, true);
}

@Bean
public FanoutExchange deadLetterExchange() {
    return new FanoutExchange(DEAD_LETTER_EXCHANGE);
}

@Bean  
public Binding deadLetterBinding() {  
    return BindingBuilder.bind(deadLetterQueue()).to(deadLetterExchange());  
}  

}
```

ErrorHandler.java to process DEAD LETTER QUEUE:

```
@Component
@RabbitListener( queues = RabbitConfig.DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE)
public class ErrorHandler {

@RabbitHandler
public void handleError(Object message) {
    System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"+message);
}

}
```

MailServiceImpl.java to process MAIL_QUEUE:

```
@Service
@RabbitListener(queues = RabbitConfig.MAIL_QUEUE)
@ConditionalOnProperty("spring.mail.host")
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

@RabbitHandler
@Override
public void sendMail(TMessageMail form) {
    //......
    try {
       mailSender.save(form);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("error in sending mail: {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thx god, I finanlly find the answer!

all the configuration are correct, the problem is all the queues like mail_queue are created before I configure dead letter queue. So when I set x-dead-letter-exchange to the queue after the queue is created, it does not take effect.

中文就是，修改队列参数后，要删除队列重建！！！这么简单的一个tip，花了我几小时。。。。。。

How to delete queue, I follow the answer.
[Deleting queues in RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742938/deleting-queues-in-rabbitmq)